# searching for nested elements in mongodb, using api nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

At this moment I have in Node.JS API written a function

```
  Board.find({ users : req.user._id})
```

It will find all documents where is id of user inside of array users,

for example 
So this function will find this document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f4b46f489dd236410d88a"),
    "name" : "first",
    "users" : [ 
        ObjectId("5a1db9e8db97d318ac70715d")
    ]
}
```

What If I will change array of users in document for array objects id

```
   {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a7f4b46f489dd236410d77c"),
        "name" : "second",
        "users" : [ 
            { _id : ObjectId("5a1db9e8db97d318ac70715d") }
        ]
}
```

How to find now this document in this situation, using only req.user._id which is saved inside object of users[]?

we can find it somehow now or not??

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change it as : `Board.find({ 'users._id' : req.user._id})`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use:

```
db.collection_name.find( { "user": { "_id" : req.user._id } } )
```